# Lucee Mappings for virtual directory is not getting mapped

Tags: mapping, admin, lucee

I have a simple `href` mapping

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font/iconsmind-s/css/iconsminds.css" />
```

I added a server mapping in Lucee Admin as:

```
virtual: \font
Resource: C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\fwone\krishi-app\views\resources\css
```

However I still get resource not found.

What am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a Lucee mapping - which runs on the server and is processed when the `.cfm` templates are executed. Versus using an HTML `<link>` tag - which executes from the users browser.

[Lucee Mappings documentation](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/cookbooks/filesystem-mapping.html)

[HTML Link Tag documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

In order for the css file reference to work using the `<link>` tag the URL must be accessible within the webroot of your site. So you should be able to reference `https://www.yourdomain.com/font/iconsmind-s/css/iconsminds.css` from your browser and get the CSS file.

Comment: Thank you. I got it confused. Yes.

Comment: No problem. Glad that helped.